# Can't save product in admin

Tags: admin, category-products

Whenever I need to edit a product in admin, I get the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in /shared/httpd/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228

I've a little little bit of debugging but and it seems that indeed, the category id's are in an array. But I don't have any clue what causes this.

```php
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => Array to string conversion
    [2] => /shared/httpd/magento/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
    [3] => 228
    [4] => Array
        (
            [params] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => simple
                    [3] => Test
                    [4] =>
                    [5] =>
                    [6] => 2019-05-17 11:23:43
                    [7] => 2019-05-17 11:23:43
                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 13
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Magento version: 2.3

PHP: 7.1.27

MySql: 10.3.13-MariaDB-1:10.3.13+maria~bionic

**Edit**: I just saw that event the category selector is always empty at every product

Comment: clear browser's cache and magento catch and try again

Comment: unfortunately it didn't helped

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an insert into the `catalog_product_entity` table.
This table has 8 columns by default.
But in your case it tries to insert 9 parameters.
The last one is strange. I have a feeling that the last parameter is the category ids that you are sending.
For some reason magento tries to insert these into the main table when it should actually insert it in the `catalog_category_product` table.
Make sure that this query `select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'category_ids';` returns this result (`attribute_id` may be different for you):

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+------+
| attribute_id | entity_type_id | attribute_code | attribute_model | backend_model                                            | backend_type | backend_table | frontend_model | frontend_input | frontend_label | frontend_class | source_model | is_required | is_user_defined | default_value | is_unique | note |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+------+
|          108 |              4 | category_ids   | NULL            | Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Category | static       | NULL          | NULL           | text           | Categories     | NULL           | NULL         |           0 |               0 | NULL          |         0 | NULL |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------+--------------+---------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------+-------------+-----------------+---------------+-----------+------+
```

Comment: The result of the query is looks exactly like yours, but with a different attribute_id (like you said)

Comment: I'm lost then. I have no other ideas.